# Every group and ring is congruence-permutable , but not necessarily congruence-distributive

Tags: universal-algebra, congruence-relations

The problem is:

> Show that every group and ring is congruence-permutable, but not necessarily  congruence-distributive.

I know that in group every normal sub group has permutable property and in every ring, every ideal has permutable property. Moreover, for not being distributive I should give an example. please Guide me.

Thanks!

Comment: What do "congruence-permutable" and "congruence-distributive" mean?

Answer (score 3):

If you compute the entire lattice of normal subgroups of the [Klein 4-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group), $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, you will see you get the smallest modular non-distributive lattice, [$M_3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice).

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be a field and $K[x,y]$ the ring of polynomials on $x$ and $y$, and coefficients in $K$.
Let $I$ be the ideal of $K[x,y]$ generated by the polynomial $f(x,y)=x$; let $J$ be the ideal generated by $g(x,y)=y$; and $H$ be the ideal generated by $h(x,y)=x+y$.

It's easy to verify that $(I \vee J) \wedge H \nleq (I \wedge H) \vee (J \wedge H)$, so that $K[x,y]$ is not congruence-distributive.
EDIT: an example of a polynomial testifying this is $h(x,y)=x+y$,

The congruence lattice of $K[x,y]$ is a sub-lattice of the congruence lattice of its group reduct;
thus you also get a group which is not congruence-distributive.